# Cannot set BottomTabNavigator color in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am unable to switch the color of my bottom tab from the default blue. I've found and tried many different ways to set the color but none of them have worked. Here is my code, currently I'm trying to set the color with tabBarColor:

```
import React from 'react';
import { HomeScreen } from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { background } from 'jimp';

const Tabs = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tabs.Navigator>
        <Tabs.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen}
          options={{            
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarColor: '#696969',
            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
              <Icon name='ios-home' color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}/>
      </Tabs.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this variant of solution with `barStyle` prop for Tab Navigator:

```
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        activeColor="#f0edf6"
        inactiveColor="#3e2465"
        barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#694fad' }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```